# Empty column error in Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, content, libraries

I am trying to load Content with Dataloader.  When I go to load the file, I get an error that says:

[image]

I hit **Yes** and it says:

[image]

I then click **OK** and nothing happens.  It just sits on the screen it was at:

[image]

Any ideas how I can possibly fix this?

EDIT:  If I hit **Next** it just starts over at the first image again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.... I had some empty columns hiding behind other columns that I didn't notice.  The following link showed me how to find and remove them.  I was then able to continue on with my load.

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/823-excel-delete-multiple-empty-columns.html